# Blue Prism - Running Multi Macros in a Process

Tags: process, macros, blueprism

I'm running into an instance error when trying to run 2 VBO Excel macros in a process.

My process is as follows (please note I'm running 2 macros back to back): Create Instance - Open Workbook - Activate Worksheet - Run Macro - Create Instance - Open Workbook - Activate Worksheet - Run Macro

Error Received for the second pass:
Workbook Not Found : Workbook named: Select Clients.xls not found in instance: 0

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

The reason you're seeing this error is due to the way Excel "instances" are logically laid out when launched by Blue Prism. **TL;DR**: Don't use the `Create Instance` action more than once, instead open all your workbooks in the same instance.

---

When creating an Excel instance, Blue Prism assigns a numeric `handle` variable to that instance. Using that handle, you'll only be able to access workbooks created in that instance. Logically, each instance would have it's own separate workbooks, worksheets, etc.:

[image: Separate Excel instances]

Because `Create Instance` creates a *completely separate* instance of Excel, you won't be able to access workbooks created within the first instance. Instead of spamming `Create Instance`, use `Open Workbook` and pass in the same `handle` you were originally assigned. From there, you'll be able to access whatever you've opened previously.

[image: One Excel instance (better method)]